# How to use alternative JDK

Tags: apache-spark

In my win 10 PC, both JDK 8 and 11 are installed. because Neo4j 4.x is only compatible with JDK 11, environment variable, JAVA_HOME, is set to path of JDK 11.

You know spark 2.x is compatible with JDK 8, when it's started as local mode, there're something wrong reported in command window. So how to set JDk path for spark 2, instead of win 10 global environment variable.

Comment: What is being reported in the command window?

Comment: For example using https://www.jenv.be/ or simply by passing a different JDK to spark! Or potentially by starting neo4j in docker

Comment: Pyspark 3.0.1, hadoop 2.7, with JDK 11,WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurredWARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform

Comment: @WilliamQue That's just a warning, that will have to be fixed eventually, but for JDK 11 the code should still work.

Comment: @Thilo Thank you!